# Is this an example of musica ficta?

Tags: theory, chromatic, modal, renaissance-music

I'm looking at the score of Carlo Gesualdo's *"Io parto" e non più dissi* from one of his madrigals. I listened to a few performances online (for example -

). I noticed that all of them alter one B-natural to a B-flat in one bar.

I'm not familiar with Renaissance modal theory, but I did learn about *musica ficta* back in school. In the passage below, the soprano sings "[May I never cease languishing] in mourning lays". "dolorosi" means mourning in Italian. It makes sense to alter that B-natural since otherwise it almost sounds "happy" to me.

[image: score]

I also looked at the original manuscripts on IMSLP. Neither has accidental on that B-natural.

[image]

[image]

I know people back in the day "knew" when to add those accidentals, but the score has almost all other accidentals included. I'm wondering if this was a mistake in the manuscript, or is it supposed to be like that and people should add a flat to the B-natural?

Answer (score 3):

I would say this is almost certainly to be understood as a ficta B♭.

In fact, there's even a saying that applies to this exact scenario: "Una nota supra la semper est canenda fa." ("A single note above la should always be sung as fa.") In other words, when singing la and you move up one step, it should always be sung as one half step away (hence B♭, "fa," as in one half step above "mi").

Comment: The part that confuses me the most is what that "fa" refers to (you mentioned fa is a half step above mi, but the text says la). I looked it up and found "...the top of a phrase bounded by a 6th or a 4th or even a tone which descends within itself should be rounded off so that the boundary interval is a minor 6th, a perfect 4th or a semitone". So in terms of melodic line, there does exist a tritone, B-natural against F at the end of the phrase. Assuming F is the "do" for the descending line, then B-flat is the "fa" and it happens to be an A ("la") here.

Comment: But I also found "An anonymous 15th-century theorist from Seville (Gallo, 1968) did state explicitly that ... when they are not ancillary to an upward-resolving leading note; this rule became common from then on". Also, as @phoog mentioned, the vertical tritone should be avoided too. So there are 3 rules to consider here and it seems that "fa mi re do is easier to sing" wins.

Comment: Before you can apply the _fa super la_ rule, you have to figure out whether the note in question is _la._  It appears to be _re,_ rather, in the hard hexachord.  There are no flats in the key signature, and at no point in the piece before this phrase is a _la._  Why is it _la_ in this phrase?

Comment: @phoog, I did some research about hexachord. I noticed two rules - 1) When you go outside the 6th note, you need to mutate to another hexachord. 2) a semitone above doesn't require a mutation. Based on the melodic lines of other voices, it suggests an F hexachord to me. And all other accidentals outside this chord are properly marked except for the one in the soprano line. So the flat is omitted because that B-natural must be a B-flat in this hexachord (the "soft" hexachord rather than the "hard" hexachord). But it doesn't explain why that B has a flat in EVERY other voice. I'm so confused.

Comment: @lbbl59 the only hexachord that doesn't contain some form of B is the natural hexachord, in which la is A.  If this is _fa super la_ then the phrase begins in the natural hexachord, but I don't see much reason for considering that this phrase begins in the natural hexachord.  Therefore, it doesn't seem to be _fa super la._ If the phrase were in the soft hexachord, the note in question should be written as B flat.  But really, how much any of this is applicable to Gesualdo is anybody's guess, because he's so far outside the system it's rather like doing functional analysis of 12-tone music.

Comment: @phoog "doing functional analysis of 12-tone music" good point. I've seen papers arguing this madrigal is in E-Phrygian since it starts and ends on it. So the rules of hexachords probably don't really apply here. But the basic principles of voice-leading and vertical intervals should still apply. It's just that Gesualdo is breaking many rules. For that soprano phrase, you either get a tritone in the melody or vertically with a different voice. And there's probably no right/wrong answer here.

Comment: @lbbl59 why would the piece being in E phrygian suggest that hexachord theory doesn't apply?

Comment: @phoog, because people were thinking in terms of modes rather than hexachords. I know that people extended theses hexachords at some point so it's hard to know what theory people applied. It's either avoiding vertical tritone or melodic tritone here.

Comment: @lbbl59 hexachord theory is inextricably linked with modal theory. Modes predated hexachords, which are a device to help singers know where the half steps are so they can sing the various modes correctly. Singers in those days would have been thinking in terms of modes _and_ hexachords simultaneously. Also, your earlier comment seems to assume that all parts would be in the same hexachord at any given time, which is not the case. For example, in the opening of Pretorius's _Es ist ein Ros entsprungen,_ the soprano is in the soft hexachord while the alto is in the natural hexachord.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be sung as a B♮.  Singing a B♭ there creates a tritone with the second and fourth parts, counting from the top, which have E♮.  It's obvious that this must be an E♮, because it is followed almost immediately in the second part by an explicit E♭.

Gesualdo is notorious for his extreme chromaticism, but if you look at his music closely it's not as completely nonsensical as it may seem at first.  A consequence of the heavy chromaticism is that the notated music is very explicit about accidentals.

These are not manuscripts, by the way, but prints that were made using movable type -- note the non-linear character of the staff lines.

Comment: “should be sung as a B♮” I thought that as well since all other accidentals are clearly marked. But I'm not sure if a tritone is prohibited in this case because it's resolved by step. The soprano also forms a minor 3rd with the 2nd and 4th part right after, which is a valid resolution. I really like Gesualdo's late madrigals. There are some voice movements that only appear more often in music a few hundred years later. Thanks for the note about the manuscripts! They are indeed made by movable types.

Comment: @lbbl59 "manuscript" means something written by hand, so it's not possible to have a manuscript made by movable type. There's another angle here, which I might add to the answer at some point, which is the fa super la rule. It could be argued that it applies here, in which case the note should be a B♭, but I don't think it does. There's also the idea that the major third is "hard," but I'm not sure how applicable it is to Gesualdo.  Note that this piece is from 1611, so it's arguably early baroque rather than renaissance. I'll have to study the whole piece and expand the answer at some point.